# I am using javascript and an ajax call to php to get data from mysql database. i want to put it in an existing div

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","admin/getmarket.php?q="+str2+"&loc="+loc,true);
```

The code in `getmarket.php` which has got the data from the database in variables `$title and $txt1`. This is put into tmp-data1 through php echo

continuing the code in javascript,

```
    var td1 = document.getElementById('tmp-data1').innerHTML;

    document.getElementById("databox1").innerHTML = td1;
```

doesn't work.

any chance of help??

Comment: Any errros? "this doesn't work" is very vague.

Comment: You're going to need to give more detail. "Doesn't work" is too vague.

Comment: The text `This is put into tmp-data1 through php echo` makes me wonder if your php script is returning something like `<div id='tmp-data1'>blah blah</div>` and you're trying to get `blah blah` before having appended the 'element' to the page. What are you doing with the response of the ajax request?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the data from inside ajax response. Read the xmlhttp.responseText inside onreadystatechange event listener and try set the value after that.

Sample code below.

```
var xmlhttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("databox1").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText['tmp-data1']; // Change this line following your response structure
    }
  };
xmlhttp.open("GET","admin/getmarket.php?q="+str2+"&loc="+loc,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
```